# Can I invoke a Kotlin coroutine from Java reflectively and wrap it in CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, kotlin-coroutines

I'm reflectively accessing a Kotlin class and trying to invoke a coroutine, wrapping it in a `CompletableFuture`.
Looking at an example from Spring, they manage to wrap such a reflective call in a `Mono` using [`kotlinx-coroutines-reactor`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/540d862afeccd72f338334e67402a974ddb150a9/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-reactor):

```
KFunction<?> function = ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(method);
Mono<Object> mono = MonoKt.mono(Dispatchers.getUnconfined(), (scope, continuation) ->
                        KCallables.callSuspend(function, getSuspendedFunctionArgs(target, args), continuation));
```

I could easily just call `Mono#toFuture()` but I'm trying to avoid dragging in a dependency to Reactor. Can I achieve the same without going through `Mono`?

Looking at [kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8), there seems to exist something similar to the above, but I can't figure out how to use it. Perhaps:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> future = FutureKt.future(
         GlobalScope.INSTANCE, Dispatchers.getUnconfined(), CoroutineStart.DEFAULT, (scope, continuation) ->
                KCallables.callSuspend(function, getSuspendedFunctionArgs(target, args), continuation));
```

But this is just a blind guess, as I have next to 0 Kotlin knowledge. Are `CoroutineStart.DEFAULT` or `GlobalScope.INSTANCE` even ok here?

Btw, how is Spring getting away with passing a `CoroutineDispatcher` (`Dispatchers.getUnconfined()`) where a `CoroutineContext` is expected? Should I be using `EmptyCoroutineContext` instead?

Comment: Generally, what you did seems fine to me. Only one question: why do you use `KCallable` and other parts of Kotlin reflection API from Java? If it makes more sense for you to use `Method` then I can prepare an example for you.

Comment: @broot I was following Spring's code, and figured using Kotlin reflection would be easier (I realized I missed posting the line where a `Method` gets turned into a `KFunction`, updated now). But if I can get away without even depending on Kotlin reflection, I'd be very grateful for an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, suspendable code is not easily callable from Java and this is by design. We can do it, but as you already noticed, this is not straightforward and requires some internal knowledge about coroutines.

Usually, it is a good idea to create an adaptation layer to translate suspendable code into something Java understands: `CompletableFuture` using [future()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/kotlinx.coroutines.guava/future.html) or blocking code using [runBlocking()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html). It is easier to write this in the Kotlin itself, so even if you consume Kotlin library from Java and the library doesn't provide such adapters to futures, you can consider adding a very thin Kotlin wrapper on the consumer side to do the translation.

If this is not possible, we can still use the same `future()` utility from Java, which you already do. This approach is a little more awkward as we need to e.g. provide values for all optional parameters.

`future()` is generally pretty easy to use. We need to provide a lambda that will invoke our suspendable function, passing a continuation we received in the lambda. That's it. However, there are multiple parameters to control the process and they complicate things. Also, we don't have to use `ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction()`, `KCallables.callSuspend()` and `getSuspendedFunctionArgs()` if we don't want to. Again, all we need to do is to invoke the function in the lambda and we can do this "the Java way".

Simple example:

```kotlin
object Database {
    @JvmStatic
    suspend fun loadUsername(userId: Int): String {
        delay(5000)
        return "User$userId"
    }
}
```

```java
// Note the method receives additional `Continuation` parameter - it is always the last param.
Method method = Database.class.getMethod("loadUsername", int.class, Continuation.class);
CompletableFuture<String> future = FutureKt.future(
        GlobalScope.INSTANCE, EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE, CoroutineStart.DEFAULT, (scope, continuation) -> {
            try {
                // We invoke the method passing its own arguments and the continuation.
                return method.invoke(null, 5, continuation);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

System.out.println("Launched, waiting...");
var result = future.get();
// Result: User5
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

We don't have to use Java reflection here, we can invoke `Database.loadUsername(5, continuation)` directly, but the question was specifically about the reflection.

Few words about params:

- `GlobalScope.INSTANCE` - this is related to the concept of [structured concurrency](https://elizarov.medium.com/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952) and using `GlobalScope` means the background operation doesn't have any "owner" to control it. In Java we don't have structured concurrency, so in most cases it is fine to simply use `GlobalScope`.
- `EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE` - I think it is safer to use `EmptyCoroutineContext` than `Dispatchers.getUnconfined()`. The difference is that unconfined dispatcher runs a coroutine inside the thread which launched or resumed it; and the empty context in this case uses a special global thread pool. Unconfined is better for performance, but it is a more advanced feature and we should use it only if we know the suspendable code and can decide it will be safe to use unconfined. It doesn't sound good for a generic adaptation layer. I'm not sure what was the reason Spring team decided to use unconfined, maybe they had a more specific use case.

BTW, I also observe `Dispatchers.getUnconfined()` can't be used as the coroutine context, but I can't explain why. Seems like some kind of a bug in IntelliJ (?). `CoroutineDispatcher` extends `AbstractCoroutineContextElement` which implements `CoroutineContext.Element` which extends `CoroutineContext`. Therefore, `CoroutineDispatcher` is a subtype of `CoroutineContext`. As a matter of fact, we can compile this code and it runs just fine, even if IntelliJ says it is wrong.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Much appreciated!